# Possible to detect that a page was redirected to via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, http-headers

Is there a way, on the server-side, to detect that a given page/script was redirected to via JavaScript?

For instance, let's say I have page.php which uses `location.href = 'tracker.php';` rather than `<?php header('Location: tracker.php'); ?>`. Is there a way for tracker.php to distinguish the former, JavaScript-based redirect from the server-side 301 redirect?

Comment: I don't think so, as you can't trust the headers... you can infer it possibly but it won't be reliable

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter to tracker.php that could be used to tell if it came from javascript or not.

Javascript:

```
location.href = 'tracker.php?redirect=1';
```

tracker.php

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["redirect"])){
        //if we're here, we know it was redirected
    }
?>
```

This will let your php script know if the redirect came from your javascript.

Comment: Yep. I'd like to know if it's possible to detect where it came from WITHOUT any indicator flag added my be, though.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is basically just another HTTP GET and you cannot see how it was triggered. The only way I can see is to manually pass a parameter or send an HTTP header to flag the JavaScript triggered redirect.

Comment: So I'm curious because once I was an advertising affiliate, and I mistakenly implemented a JavaScript redirect to a merchant site rather than letting the  click event trigger the redirect (I was doing an event.preventDefault(), doing some tracking, and then doing another redirect), and the affiliate network banned me. I don't know how they figured out this was happening.

Comment: That is interesting, AFAIK - and I might be missing something here - clicking that link and setting location.href should be equivalent unless there are other things that happen on click which would somehow flag the event.

Comment: Ah! I just remembered...they were detecting that the redirect was artificial rather than (desirably) from a link click. So I am actually asking the wrong question in this thread.